# How do I turn off wget proxy?

Tags: networking, proxy, reverse-proxy, wget

I had been using a proxy for a long time. Now I need to remove it. I have forgotten how I have added the proxy to wget. Can someone please help me get back to the normal wget where it doesn't use any proxy. As of now, I'm using

```
wget <link> --proxy=none
```

But I'm facing a problem when I'm installing using a pre-written script. It's painstaking to search all through the scripts and change each command.
Any simpler solution will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Check your

1. `~/.wgetrc`
2. `/etc/wgetrc`

and remove proxy settings.

Or use `wget --no-proxy` command line option to override them.

Comment: I edited wgetrc and made use_proxy=off. But it still give the same error.

Comment: Did you check `wget --no-proxy`.  What exact error you are seeing

Comment: What about `HTTPS_PROXY` and `HTTP_PROXY` environment variable. Will this method bypass these proxies as well?

Comment: @PSKP the order is like this: 1. command_line options, 2. environment variables, 3. config files

Answer (score 7):

In case your OS is `alpine`/`busybox` then the `wget` might vary from the one used by @Logu.

There the correct command is

```sh
wget --proxy off http://server:port/
```

Running `wget --help` outputs:

```sh
/ # wget --help
BusyBox v1.31.1 () multi-call binary.

Usage: wget [-c|--continue] [--spider] [-q|--quiet] [-O|--output-document FILE]
        [-o|--output-file FILE] [--header 'header: value'] [-Y|--proxy on/off]
        [-P DIR] [-S|--server-response] [-U|--user-agent AGENT] [-T SEC] URL...

Retrieve files via HTTP or FTP

        --spider        Only check URL existence: $? is 0 if exists
        -c              Continue retrieval of aborted transfer
        -q              Quiet
        -P DIR          Save to DIR (default .)
        -S              Show server response
        -T SEC          Network read timeout is SEC seconds
        -O FILE         Save to FILE ('-' for stdout)
        -o FILE         Log messages to FILE
        -U STR          Use STR for User-Agent header
        -Y on/off       Use proxy
```